# NetBIOS replying only to external requests

Tags: linux, networking, unix, netbios

I have some IPs on the internal network I'm 100% sure have netbios enabled. (I say "internal network", but all the IP octets differ. It is just the same institution and geographical location).

If I perform the test locally using either [Alla Bezroutchko's NBTscan version 1.5.1](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/nbtscan), or [Steve Friedl's namesake](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html), I get no results. If I use [this online tool](https://w3dt.net/tools/netbios) I get results like the one below:

[image]

It doesn't replies to pings either from my machine or from online tools, but I know the host is up. Running `nmap` shows open TCP ports. Interestingly, when `nmap` is run locally it doesn't show two ports (139 (netbios-ssn) and 445 (microsoft-ds)) ***that are present when running it [online](https://w3dt.net/tools/portscan)***.

If I run `nbtstat` from home, using the same IP as argument, I get

```
nbtscan -v <IP>
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from <IP>


NetBIOS Name Table for Host <IP>:

Name             Service          Type             
----------------------------------------
REDACTED         <00>             UNIQUE
REDACTED         <00>              GROUP
REDACTED         <1c>              GROUP
REDACTED         <20>             UNIQUE
REDACTED         <1b>             UNIQUE
REDACTED         <1e>              GROUP
REDACTED         <1d>             UNIQUE
__MSBROWSE__  <01>              GROUP

Adapter address: REDACTED
----------------------------------------
```

What's the reason for the discrepancy in the answer for local and external replies? What can I do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This is an incident of [NetBIOS over IP, or NetBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP) being enabled on your network while normal netbios is not.

Frankly, this is a definite security concern. This sort of information should *not* be available. Ideally, the tool should time out and not show any information.

Comment: But how would it explain no results when the tests are performed locally? I can understand being open to the whole world, but being open to the world and closed to the local network?!?!

Comment: NetBIOS is actually blocked locally at each firewall...it's NetBT that isn't.